# Provide method to handle GET on a Loopback model, whose db is null and base class is 'Model'

Tags: rest, handler, loopbackjs

### RESOLVED. MY BAD.

Skip to the end of this post, and change http://localhost:3000/api/Setan/getXid/1 to http://localhost:3000/api/Setans/getXid/1 ... and it works.

Use the plural form in the URL....

### My comment on UPDATE 02 is also invalid.

---

Seems like I can't attach a remote method on a model that's configured this way in model-config.json:

```
"Dashboard": {
  "dataSource": null,
  "public": true
}
```

*) I'm using loopback ver. 3.0.0.

Screenshot of "lb model":

[image]

I want to have an endpoint like this: http://localhost:3000/api/Dashboard/experiment/2017-04-03T14:16:44-05:00

So, my common/models/dashboard.js is like this:

```
module.exports = function(Dashboard) {
  Dashboard.remoteMethod('experiment', {
    accepts: [
      {arg: 'dateStr', type: 'string', required: true}
    ],
    http: {path: '/experiment/:dateStr', verb: 'get'},
    returns: {arg: 'count', type: 'number'}
  });    

  Dashboard.experiment = function(dateStr, cb) {
    cb(null, {answer: "yes"});
  }
};
```

Called in from a REST client, I got:

```
{
  "error": {
    "statusCode": 404,
    "name": "Error",
    "message": "There is no method to handle GET /Dashboard/experiment/2017-04-03T14:16:44-05:00",
    "stack": "Error: There is no method to handle GET /Dashboard/experiment/2017-04-03T14:16:44-05:00\n    
      at restUrlNotFound (/Users/raka/Development/MyAngular/NewBeginning/baktun-dashboard-server/node_modules/strong-remoting/lib/rest-adapter.js:366:17)\n .... "
  }
}
```

So... I tried with another case, this time a model that extends Model (just like Dashboard), but db is not-null (I set to to memory-db). Here's the entry in model-config.js:

```
"Manusia": {
  "dataSource": "db",
  "public": true
}
```

And in common/models/manusia.js exactly the same remote-method definition:

```
module.exports = function(Manusia) {
  Manusia.remoteMethod('experiment', {
    accepts: [
      {arg: 'dateStr', type: 'string', required: true}
    ],
    http: {path: '/experiment/:dateStr', verb: 'get'}, 
    returns: {arg: 'count', type: 'number'}
  });    

  Manusia.experiment = function(dateStr, cb) {
    cb(null, {answer: "yes"});
  }
};
```

It works, I called http://localhost:3000/api/Manusia/experiment/2017-04-03T14:16:44-05:00 from REST client, and I get:

```
{
  "count": {
    "answer": "yes"
  }
}
```

**The question**: is there a step I'm missing in order to be able to specify GET handler / remote method for a model that doesn't have datasource?

I know I can always write it in /server/boot/routes.js or server/server.js ( https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Add-a-custom-Express-route.html )... but..., I like to have my stuffs neatly organized under common/models... so that's why first I want to know if I can really achieve that by having a remote method on non-persisted & "non-attached to any db" model.

Oh wait, actually there is a better reason to have it in a model; so Incan have the corresponding method in the generated angular-client lib. So yes, I need it.

**UPDATE 01**

Actually it is unreliable. I cannot reproduce the success case in some (many) ocassions..., and sometimes (few times) I can.

So....

**UPDATE 02**

Found out that the name of remote method is registered globally. Meaning: you can't both these (the share the same name for the remote method):

```
Kuda.remoteMethod('yeah', ...)
```

and

```
Anjing.remoteMethod('yeah', ...)
```

You must ensure uniqueness of remoteMethod name. So, this one is ok:

```
Kuda.remoteMethod('yeah', ...)
Anjing.remoteMethod('hurray', ...)
```

But still, it doesn't work for the no-datasource Model.

**UPDATE 03**

Back to square one. Seems like it's unreliable / inconsistent. Failing again in most cases, even after taking into account UPDATE-02

[image]

Almost identical, but different success status. http://localhost:3000/api/Manusia/getId/1 works, while http://localhost:3000/api/Setan/getXid/1 doesn't work.

Any clues?

Thanks,
Raka